# Я живу в огромной стране - России, и говорю по-русски

Tags: пунктуация

В этом предложении правильно выбраны знаки препинания? Как можно объяснить постановку запятой?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ исправлен

1. **Одно тире** ставится при обособлении приложения, если приложение выражает **конкретное** значение, а предшествующее определяемое слово имеет **общее** или образное значение: *На совещании министров иностранных дел **стран — членов Организации американских государств** выступил министр иностранных дел Кубы.*

Розенталь, п.10, примечание 2  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

2. ***Я живу** в огромной стране — России, и **(я) говорю** по-русски.*

При постановке **запятой** предложение считается сложным (ССП). Такой вариант допускается **при большой расчлененности** однородных сказуемых (если они значительно удалены друг от друга, имеют собственные распространенные зависимые слова и т.д.).  Тогда второе предложение в составе ССП является **неполным** (пропущено подлежащее "я").

3. Однако в данном случае  **запятую нежелательно ставить**, так приложение при постановке одного тире тесно примыкает к определяемому существительному:

***Я живу в огромной стране — России и говорю по-русски.***

Сравнить с примером из Розенталя (п.10, примечание 4): *Я начал говорить об условиях, о неравенстве, **о людях — жертвах жизни и о людях — владыках её*** (М. Г.).

Comment: А если простое предложение? Ведь здесь уже явно выглядит как простое. *Поэтому союз И не может объединить сказуемые в одну фразу* — нет такого правила.

Comment: Хотя да, на вопрос вы ответили — объяснили запятую. Но вряд ли автор предложения именно это задумывал.

Comment: То есть так нельзя? *Я живу в огромной стране, России, и говорю по-русски.* Супер! Грамматика же это запрещает (в ваших фантазиях). Нет здесь большой расчленённости.

Comment: *но так никто не делает* — поэтому мне нравится больше с запятыми.

Comment: А от меня вам что нужно? Я объяснила знаки для данного варианта. И вообще, нарушаете правила. Комментарии не для дискуссии, давайте альтернативный ответ и пишите там что хотите. Я. пожалуй, так и буду делать. Вы в комментариях можете только уточнить детали моего ответа, а не критиковать его.

Comment: Вы написали "правильно". Если бы вы написали "знаки можно объяснить так", то вопросов бы не было.

Comment: Считайте, что там так написано. Всё?

Comment: А ваше "правильно" подразумевает, что это лучший вариант. Но не стоит забывать, что присоединение — это сказанное вдобавок, вряд ли это хотели.

Comment: В примере Розенталя не пояснительное тире, а дефисное (*о людях-жертвах и о людях-владыках*).